# How to give an optimization to counting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Given an ordered list of values, I want to group any members having the same value and output a count of each value:

For example,

```
input: [1,1,1,3,3,2,1,1] 
output:
[(1,3),(3,2),(2,1),(1,2)]

input:['a','a','b','b','c','a']
output:
[('a',2),(b,2),(c,1),(a,1)]
```

Additionally, I want to treat the first and last values specially. What is the optimal way to do this?

Comment: How does your algorithm look like?

Comment: I compare the current element with the previous, if same, counter++. Till they are different save the counter, and reset it to zero for the next element.

Comment: Dealing with boundary conditions is O(1) and therefore not worth optimizing...

Answer (score 0):

I am writing down a rough solution for this problem:

```
main()
{
     char arr[100];
     int count[100],j=0,i,n;
     for(i=0;i<100;i++)
     {
         count[i] = 0;
     }
     scanf("%d\n",&n);
     scanf("\n%c",&arr[0]);
     count[j]=1;
     for(i=1;i<n;i++)
     {
         scanf("%c",&arr[i]);
         if(arr[i-1]==arr[i])
         {
             count[j]++;
         }
         else
         {
             j++;
             count[j]=1;
         }
     }
     for(i=0;i<=j;i++)
     {
         printf("%d\n",count[i]);
     }
}
```

Here i am reading n characters from user then checking it current character with the previous one after reading the current character. I am keeping a separate array for count.

Hope that helps...